# Copying data from one oracle database to another oracle database using C#

Tags: c#, performance, oracle, copying

What is the standard way of copying data from one oracle database to another.

1) Read data from source table and copy to temp table on destination using configuration( i.e. there are more than 1 table and each table has separate temp table)
2) Right now there is no clob data, but in future clob data might be used.
3) Read everything to memory(if large data read in chunks)

Should not use Oracle links
Should not use files
Code should be only using C# but not any database procedures.

Comment: Voted to close on the grounds that, by precluding the obvious database links, database procedures, file transfers mechanisms, the solution will only be relevent to people who REALLY enjoy re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @Gary Its a standard procedure in the company not to have any db links between production database. Hence we are suppose to do using Middle-Tier applications. I think we can export to file, then read the file and write to db, but that would be more work when we only want to read from source table and write to target table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that I've used to do this is to use a DataReader on the source database and just perform inserts on the target database (using [Bind Parameters](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html) for sure).

Note that the DataReader is excellent at not using much memory as it moves through a table (I believe that by default it uses a Fast Forward, Read Only cursor).  This means that only a small amount of data is held in memory at a given time.

Here are the things to watch out for:

**Relationships**

If you're working with data that has relationships, you're going to need to deal with that.  There are two ways that I've seen to deal with this:

1. Temporarily drop the relationships in the target database before doing the copy, then recreate them after.
2. Copy the data in the correct order for the relationships to work correctly (this is usually pretty difficult / inefficient)

**Auto Generated Id Values**

These columns are usually handled by disabling the auto increment functionality for the given table and allowing identity insert (I'm using some SQL Server terms, I can't remember how it works on Oracle).

**Transactions**

If you're moving a lot of data, transactions will be expensive.

**Repeatability / Deleting Target Data**

Unless you're way more awesome than the rest of us, you'll probably have to run this thing more than once (at least during development).  That means you might want a way to delete the target data.

**Platform Specific Methods**

In SQL Server, there are ways to perform bulk inserts that are blazingly fast (by giving up little things like referential integrity checking).  There might be a similar feature within the Oracle toolset.

**Table / Column Metadata**

I haven't had to do this in Oracle yet, but it looks like you can get metadata on tables and columns using the views mentioned [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables014.htm).

Comment: @RQDQ As we are keeping source data in memory there is a limit we can put. If the source data is more than memory limit, Is it possible to read upto memory limit (i.e. read data in chunks) and insert the data into the target table. Loop this until all the source data is copied to target. We are planning to make this application generic in the sense that the application doesn't know what is the source table and what is destination only at runtime it is provided with these values. So in the future any new changes in the table structure, or any new source tables and target tables should b handled

Comment: The good thing about using a DataReader for this is it doesn't hold all of the data in memory.  It just runs a cursor through the data (handling paging / chunking in the background).  As for deal with being able to copy any table, just write your code so that it reads the systems views for table structure.

Comment: @RQDQ You mean to say read from the user_tab_columns table and generate the insert and select query for each table once when the application starts and reuse the queries for each insert.

Comment: @bunny - yes - that's exactly what I was thinking.  That's what I've done in the past and it has worked pretty well.

Comment: @RQDQ Ok. now I have the Select and Insert queries ready, when we read data from the DataReader. Are we suppose to insert each row into database one at a time or bundle a bunch of rows and then insert into database? And also because we are not reading from one source table, how can we retrieve data from data reader. I mean data for each column and mapping it to the insert statement.

Comment: @bunny - In general, I've just done one table at a time copying the values for all columns (in other words, one reader for each table).  I've usually just done a single insert at a time, but Oracle might have a faster way (I don't know what Oracle does for bulk insertion of data).

Comment: @RQDQ Thanks a lot for all the information you provided. I ll start working on them. One of the senior developer told me to extract data using data reader and get that data into DataTable map the dataTable schema with the target table and make DataAdapter.Update(dataTable). Only take few rows based on the configuration and insert into the tables until the DataReader is done. Then at the end commit.